# Generate Report that shows which Ids matched between two SQL tables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, excel

I have an SQL query that I am running to insert values from table1 to table2 only where the Ids of the table row match:

```
UPDATE PT
SET CreditInvoiceAmount = CSV.CreditInvoiceAmount
,CreditInvoiceDate = CSV.CreditInvoiceDate
,CreditInvoiceNumber = CSV.CreditInvoiceNumber
,CreditDeniedDate = CSV.CreditDeniedDate
,CreditDeniedReasonId = CSV.CreditDeniedReasonId
,CreditDeniedNotes = CSV.CreditDeniedNotes
,StatusId = CASE 
                WHEN CSV.CreditInvoiceDate IS NULL
                    AND CSV.CreditDeniedDate IS NOT NULL
                        THEN 7
                ELSE 8
            END
FROM PermanentTable PT
INNER JOIN TemporaryCsvUpload CSV ON PT.Id = CSV.Id
```

I would say about 60% of the Ids in the temporary table will match the Ids in the permanent table. I would like to generate some kind of report to display which Ids matched and which didn't. The format in which I display that information doesn't really matter (HTML table, excel sheet, whatever). I'm not sure how I would use a query to get that information so I could display it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What SQL Server version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show all the IDs, and whether they were in one or both tables, try this; it will return a list of IDs that are in at least one table, with a flag indicating which table or tables they appear in:

```
Select ISNULL(p.ID, t.ID) as ID
, case when p.ID is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end as InPermanentTable
, case when t.ID is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end as InTemporaryTable
from PermanentTable p
full outer join TemporaryCsvUpload t
on p.ID = t.ID
```

To return just the IDs from the temporary table, along with a flag indicating whether they were in the permanent table or not, use this:

```
Select t.ID
, case when p.ID is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end as InPermanentTable
from TemporaryCsvUpload t
left join PermanentTable p
on p.ID = t.ID
```

Comment: How could I only display fields with a Y in them, hiding the N or null values?

Comment: @CavanFlynn I have edited to address your comment - is the second query above what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, perfect. Do you have any suggestions for the best way to display the results of the query in a view?

Comment: It would really depend on what information your users need, in terms of other columns to join in or aggregations to perform on those results.  The query above should be fairly efficient, so you could just drop it into a view as is if you want.  If you are having trouble with the syntax for a view, you should probably post that as a new question.

Comment: @CavanFlynn happy to help.  If this answers your question, please consider marking it "accepted."

Answer (score 1):

The `MERGE` statement will fit what you are looking.  It is able to update those that match, insert those that don't, and report back to you what matched and what didn't.  It is best to log the output to another table.

```
MERGE PermanentTable P --target
USING TemporaryCsvUpload T --source
ON P.Id = T.Id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE P
    SET CreditInvoiceAmount = T.CreditInvoiceAmount
    ,CreditInvoiceDate = T.CreditInvoiceDate
    ,CreditInvoiceNumber = T.CreditInvoiceNumber
    ,CreditDeniedDate = T.CreditDeniedDate
    ,CreditDeniedReasonId = T.CreditDeniedReasonId
    ,CreditDeniedNotes = T.CreditDeniedNotes
    ,StatusId = CASE 
                    WHEN T.CreditInvoiceDate IS NULL
                        AND T.CreditDeniedDate IS NOT NULL
                            THEN 7
                    ELSE 8
                END
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (P columns go here)
    VALUES (T columns go here)
OUTPUT $action, Inserted.Id --Inserted will show both inserted and updated to IDs
    , Deleted.Id --Deleted will show IDs that were changed in the UPDATE
```

Since you are only updating/inserting, when the action is UPDATE, the Inserted and Deleted Id will be the same.

You can change the `WHEN NOT MATCHED` to log to a separate table as well, instead of to the PermanentTable.

Comment: Looks good, for the purpose of my project I only need to update the rows where the Ids do match and report which Ids did and which didnt. No inserting of Ids that didn't match.