# Need helping adjusting SQL query involving table joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I have two tables: `PermanentTable` and `TemporaryTable`.

There are 7 columns in the `TemporaryTable`:

```
Id, CreditInvoiceDate, CreditInvoiceNumber, CreditInvoiceAmount, 
CreditDeniedDate, CreditDeniedReasonId, CreditDeniedNotes.
```

All these columns are also in the `PermanentTable` and have been previously filled in if the `Id` matched one in the `TemporaryTable`.

I have a query that returns the Ids in the `TemporaryTable` and a column that displays a 'Y' is the Id was matched in the `PermanentTable` and an 'N' if it was not. If they were matched, either the `CreditInvoiceDate`, `CreditInvoiceNumber`, and `CreditInvoiceAmount` or the `CreditDeniedDate`, `CreditDeniedReasonId`, and `CreditDeniedNotes` will be filled in with data (but not all 6). A column called `AuthNumber` will also be filled in if they matched. My query returns those.

**Query**

```
Select 
    t.Id, p.AuthNumber,
    p.CreditInvoiceDate, p.CreditInvoiceNumber,
    p.CreditInvoiceAmount, p.CreditDeniedDate,
    p.CreditDeniedReasonId, p.CreditDeniedNotes,
    case 
        when p.Id is not null 
        then 'Y' else 'N' 
    end as Matched
from 
    TemporaryCsvUpload t 
left join 
    PermanentTable p on p.Id = t.Id
```

**Result**

[image]

This is the point I have gotten to, but here is where I am trying to go:

I would like to adjust this query so I can get rid of the Matched column at the end and instead have 2 Id columns. One containing the Ids in the `TemporaryTable` that matched in the `PermanentTable` and one containing the ones that didn't. If the Ids didn't match then none of the other fields will be filled in, so there is no need to check.

Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious, how is this different from your other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729334/generate-report-that-shows-which-ids-matched-between-two-sql-tables/31730164#31730164)?

Comment: Because I am trying to separate the Id column into Id Matched and Not Matched and only display the additional columns that are generated if matched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below query should help you:

```
Select  case when p.Id is not null then t.Id else null end as tempMatchedId, 
case when p.Id is null then t.Id else null end as tempUnmatchedId, 
case when p.Id is not null then p.AuthNumber else null end as AuthNumber,
case when p.Id is not null then p.CreditInvoiceDate else null end as CreditInvoiceDate, 
case when p.Id is not null then p.CreditInvoiceNumber else null end as CreditInvoiceNumber,
case when p.Id is not null then p.CreditInvoiceAmount else null end as CreditInvoiceAmount, 
case when p.Id is not null then p.CreditDeniedDate else null end as CreditDeniedDate,
case when p.Id is not null then p.CreditDeniedReasonId else null end as CreditDeniedReasonId, 
case when p.Id is not null then p.CreditDeniedNotes else null end as CreditDeniedNotes
from TemporaryCsvUpload t 
left join PermanentTable p 
on p.Id = t.Id
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I had to make some slight adjustments though so I'll put in an edit

Answer (score 3):

The following should work just as well as the other answer, and be a lot easier to read:

```
Select  p.Id as tempMatchedId, 
        case when p.Id is null then t.Id end as tempUnmatchedId, 
        p.AuthNumber,
        p.CreditInvoiceDate, 
        p.CreditInvoiceNumber,
        p.CreditInvoiceAmount, 
        p.CreditDeniedDate,
        p.CreditDeniedReasonId, 
        p.CreditDeniedNotes
from TemporaryCsvUpload t 
left join PermanentTable p 
       on p.Id = t.Id
```